# What SCCM roles should I install on my secondary sites?

Tags: sccm, system-center, sccm-2012, hierarchy

In the company I'm currently working, we'd like to install System Center Configuration Manager to automaticly deploy Windows 7 images and software.

I have been conducting some research on installing, configuring and running SCCM in a closed lab-environment. These tests have been succesful and now we are making the step to installing SCCM on our servers.

The company has 3 offices which are connected to the main office via VPN.
So network reliability and speed aren't that good.

The main office will host a Standalone Primary Site and the 2 other offices will run a Secondary Server.
As the network connection isn't the best, I was thinking about moving as much as possible to the secondary sites and only send syncing traffic over the VPN.

I have worked out a little schema and I hoped you could point out any mistakes or improvements that can be done.

[image: SCCM Site Setup]

The Secretariaat is a seperate network in the same building as the main office and testing has shown that our trusts etc. are configured correctly so that the Secretariaat network can connect to the resources on the Main Server.

Although the schema shows 4 servers per site, all site roles will be installed on 1 site server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have chosen to go with the hierarchy shown in the picture above.

We have fixed the issues with contacting clients in our seperate forest.
There were some minor changes necessary in our Active Directory and the firewall of our clients. We also had to put our test computer in the correct VLAN and network.

In 'Brugge' and 'Oostende' we will install secondary sites, which will be controlled via the primary site in 'Sint-Michiels', which also controls the clients in 'Secretariaat'